# iText 5.5 - Java - HTML and CSS

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to convert HTML into a PDF using iText 5.5.
There is an Exception thrown in the `CSSUtils` class (line 289 - `processFont` method).

The styleAndRest String array has just 'inherit' as a value.
**Does anyone know how to get around this issue?**

I did try a different approach (scraping the previous code posted before this edit), and I get a different exception:

```
public class TestItext {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\jim.willmore\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\testingpdf.pdf"));
            document.open();
            XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new FileReader("C:\\Users\\jim.willmore\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\triptix-pdf-template-3314082183865567231.html"));
            document.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The exception I get is:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.125em"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:422)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.FontSizeTranslator.getFontSize(FontSizeTranslator.java:186)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.FontSizeTranslator.translateFontSize(FontSizeTranslator.java:165)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.AbstractTagProcessor.startElement(AbstractTagProcessor.java:120)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline.open(HtmlPipeline.java:105)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker.startElement(XMLWorker.java:103)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.startElement(XMLParser.java:372)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.state.TagAttributeState.process(TagAttributeState.java:80)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parseWithReader(XMLParser.java:237)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:215)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(XMLWorkerHelper.java:174)
    at TestItext.main(TestItext.java:19)
```

I guess the more generic question is - if the HTML processed has embedded CSS, can iText process the HTML? Can iText handle HTML5?

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace with root exception.

Comment: I bet you, any more, the creator of this library will appear with your answer. He's like the magical `iText` genie.